# python matplotlib save plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

It must be easy but I still cant figure it out. Suppose I am reading lot of txt file with glob module.And do some processing, and later plotting them with matplotlib.

```
import glob
ascii = sorted(glob.glob('C:/Users/ENAMUL/PYTHON/*.txt')) 
for count,i in enumerate(ascii):
........
........
```

Now I want to save those figures. I can do it like this which will save them by counting numbers.

```
plt.savefig(str(count)+'png')
```

But if I want to save them by taking their input file name, how can I do that? Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop, `i` contains the name of the file, so:

```
import os.path

....

plt.savefig(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(i))[0] + '.png')
```

It works like this. `os.path.basename` returns the filename:

```
In [2]: os.path.basename('foo/bar/baz.bat')
Out[2]: u'baz.bat'
```

Then `splitext` does the obvious:

```
In [3]: os.path.splitext(os.path.basename('foo/bar/baz.bat'))
Out[3]: (u'baz', u'.bat')
```

So:

```
In [4]: os.path.splitext(os.path.basename('foo/bar/baz.bat'))[0] + '.png'
Out[4]: u'baz.png'
```

If you want to keep the path, just remove the `basename` call, and only use `splitext`:

```
In [5]: os.path.splitext('foo/bar/baz.bat')[0] + '.png'
Out[5]: u'foo/bar/baz.png'
```

Comment: what is the benefit of going this extra route, when the names are already stored in ``ascii``?

Comment: @Schorsch The names in `ascii` still contain their path and extension.

Answer (score 0):

You store the file name in `ascii` - so you should be able to use it when saving the figure:

```
plt.savefig(ascii[count] + '.png')
```

Comment: That would produce a filename with a double extension `.txt.png`. Probably not what was intended.

Comment: actually this line does my job. But I also understand the explanation on top. Right now it saves the figure in my input folder. If I create a folder for figure, how can I directed them to that folder?

Comment: if you want to redirect your output, I would suggest you use @RolandSmith answer - and put a new path before the file name.